# Task scheduler wont run my .net console app

Tags: .net, taskscheduler

I have an app to write data into excel. It works well when I run the .exe manually by double clicking it.
Now I want to run is as a scheduled task, but see a .net error in the event viewer:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
>      at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbooks.Open(System.String, System.Object, System.Object, System.Object, System.Object, System.Object, System.Object, System.Object, System.Object, System.Object, System.Object, System.Object, System.Object, System.Object, System.Object))

Below is the partial code:

```vb
    Dim testworkbook As Workbook = Nothing
    Dim testworksheet As Worksheet = Nothing
    Dim countcell As Integer = 1
    Dim failcell As Integer = 3
    Dim Machine As String
    Dim WMBBdate As String
    Dim OSCmachine As String
    Dim OSCdate As String

    Dim xls As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
    xls.DisplayAlerts = False
    xls.AutomationSecurity = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoAutomationSecurity.msoAutomationSecurityLow


    testworkbook = xls.Workbooks.Open("\\YY088132\Users\310288557\Desktop\Virtual Line auto email\Test3.xlsx")
    testworksheet = testworkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    testworksheet.UsedRange.Clear()
    testworksheet.Cells.Font.Color = ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Black)
```

I suspect it stops at line that open workbook.

I have tried every possible solution that I found on google such as:

1. create *Desktop* folder at `syswow64` and `system32`
2. DCOM config
3. And more.

Comment: Your code is actually starting an Excel instance, loading a document and working with it. If Excel isn't installed, or the scheduled task's account has no permission to use it, you'll get an error. Excel interop is *not* used for server-side processing for precisely this reason.

Comment: BTW randomly creating forlders, like *Desktop* inside the *System* folder can only lead to problems and deleting OS files.

Comment: The solution is to *not* use Excel interop. Use a library like [EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/wiki/Getting-Started) to create and edit `xlsx` files without even having Excel installed. `xlsx` is a ZIP package containing XML files. You could even edit those files directly but EPPlus makes it a lot easier

Comment: Check the [EPPlus sample code for formatting and styling](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/wiki/Formatting-and-styling). The API is quite similar to Excel without requiring conversions to COM/OLE values

Comment: Pretty unlikely that the 4 previous comments will change anything.  The code is using a file present on another machine.  That makes it very important to configure the task with a user account that has access to that machine.  The default account (System) doesn't.  Write an event handler for AppDomain.UnhandledException to get better crash info.